# Fetch as Google error 403

Tags: seo, google-search-console, drupal, 403-forbidden, fetch-as-google

2 weeks ago, Google started being unable access my website anymore. In Webmaster Tools I can't fetch any pages, always getting error 403, and the website has been completely dropped from Google search results.

I can't figure why it suddenly can't see it anymore. I've checked .htaccess and there is nothing that blocks Google crawlers, and robots.txt is fine too.

The site is accessible normally for users.
Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Use a user-agent switcher and visit your site as Googlebot. What do you see?

Comment: i see the page normaly, nothing changes..

Comment: all the permissions on the files, and all the files seems ok!
Its strange that before worked fine and nothing has been changed, no hacks.
I dont if google changed something.. Realy this thing is getting me crazy whole day!

Comment: It seems like some level is prohibiting the IP addresses of googlebot, as just the user-agent of googlebot does not cause 403.  Maybe a piece of software is checking that if user-agent is googlebot then IP must be a google IP, but that software got the IP test backwards.

Comment: now it's working and i haven't changed anything!!

Comment: Any meta tags blocking googlebot?

Comment: nope, all clear.

Comment: Have you spoken to your hosting provider about this? If you control the server it's possible that some other bit of network kit (load-balancers/firewalls) was getting in the way. If you don't own and control the server it could have been poor management from another site on the host.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you figure this out? Was a content manager involved? Pmwiki, perhaps?

Comment: Huh, i can't remeber what the problem was. But i think in .htaccess i needed to give access to google crawlers, in some way they were bloccked from accesing.

Answer (score 1):

I would speak to your hosting provider, it sounds like maybe something they did on a server or network level.

If they aren't helpful with it you could maybe speak to others with the same host to see if they had similar problems around the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem ,if your site is at 40-50% don't worry to much ,try to do again it should let you do again if it doesn't then there is problem with your DNS make sure your google robot txt in your site allows google to follow index